# Where should business logic go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, saas

I working on a Saas application that will be using ASP.NET MVC 4 & SQL Server.  I am planning to have a data layer (using EF5), a service layer (possible only have RESTful services), a DTO layer, and Web UI layer.  Later on, I am planning to extend this application to mobile platform, for both Android & iPhone ... maybe windows tablet.

Usually, one would create a separate layer for domain objects where business rules are contained.  However, in my case, if I did that, then I would have to replicate the rules again for android ... and yet again for iphone.  So, I was thinking to have the business rules within the service layer itself.  However, for whatever reason that doesn't feel right.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: why would you have to replicate the rules for android? business rules are in the domain, unless your talking about 'presentation logic'. you should have a domain layer which contains your business objects and associated business logic. then other layers reference this.

Comment: Everything initially would be written in .net.  If I wrote my rules in a separate business layer, would I be able to make use of the same dlls in android or the iPhone os?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "business rule" you would enforce across the different applications?

Comment: Something like: When a new user account is created, they system should check to make sure that username doesn't already exist.  This is just a simple rule, but there could be more complex rules that should live in one place and could be accessed by different apps on different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presentation layer must be what it is.. just a presentation layer. Your business rules should not be there. 
I understand that your DTO's will be the objects that will feed your clients (android, iphone, web,etc..), so there's no need to transfer your business objects to the UI. Keep your business layer isolated in the server side and make your clients work with it just to get the data they need to show.

My suggestion is to make the presentation layer agnostic of the business rules. Using this approach will make your solution scalable and easy to extend. Is a good way to apply separation of concerns.

Saying that.. You might be worried about how to share your DTO's across different platforms. I think the best approach would be to not feed your presentation layer with .NET objects since you are planning to use different programming languages and technologies in your presentation layer. **JSON** and REST could play very well for your problem.
I suggest to use Asp.net Web Api to work with json objects. Objective-c, Java and Javascript (for your Web UI) can work with this kind of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have a service layer. The business logic should be behind it.

```
Business layer -> (shared business objects) -> service layer -> (shared DTOs) -> presentation layers
```

Where the presentation layers are MVC4, Android, IPhone etc. They can all share the same DTOs but serialized differently.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, duplicating the rules for each platform is the way to go (because it separates the processing between different devices) however from a maintenance, consistency, etc. perspective you should place the business rules in a workflow that is within / parallel to the service layer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658103.aspx